# Is it possible to retrieve and use a handlebars template from an XHR, instead of using the script tag?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

The handlebars documentation shows that one inserts a template in a page by adding a "script" node:

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div>
        <h3>cars</h3>
        <fieldset>
            {{#each model}}
            <label class="labels">
                {{answer}}
            </label>
            <br>
            {{/each}}
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</script>
```

Then doing:

```
var source = $(#myTemplate).html();
template = Handlebars.compile(source);
```

and then applying a context to generate the output html.

But instead of inserting the script in the page, I wanted to just get everything from the script tags from my web server. But when I do try to compile the source from my web server, the browser console complains about an unexpected "<" .

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible.

In this code:

```
var source = $(#myTemplate).html();
template = Handlebars.compile(source);
```

Just replace the first line with an ajax call that retrieves the HTML via an Ajax call and then compile the results of fetching the HTML.  So, instead of getting the HTML from a script tag, you're getting it from an ajax call just like you would fetch any other data from a web server with an ajax call.

If you're trying that and getting an error, then you will have to be a lot more specific about exactly what code you're using, what error you're getting and what result you're getting back from the ajax call for us to know where you've gone wrong with that.  But, if you implement it properly, it's perfectly reasonable to do it that way.  You will not want the `<script>` tags in the HTML you get via the Ajax call, just the raw HTML snippet that represents the template.